# Online testing platform

Tags: testing

What are good and free online testing platforms for mathematics? Is there any who can easily display math formulas? Any allowing LaTeX code? Apparently the only way to insert formulas in Google Forms is with pictures, weschool doesn't even allow to insert image in the answer, do we have better choices?

Comment: Have you tried WebWork?

Comment: I haven't used it in this manner myself. However, the CoCalc platform (cocalc.com) can do LaTeX formulas and creates a worksheet. It is primarily for mathematical programming.

Comment: Ximera probably has this capability, though I don't know how easy it is to set up your own instance.

Comment: [MyOpenMath](http://myopenmath.com) is written in php, I believe, so it has nicely-rendered math.

Comment: "Platform" without "contents" (problems, solutions, guidance) is quite useless...

Comment: Have you tried [Graspable Math](https://graspablemath.com/)? You can add geogebra tiles in which you can insert LaTeX formulas.